# UTF-8 and !# shell scripts

Tags: unix, configuration, bash, utf-8

Is there a way to configure bash on Linux (red hat and ubuntu) to allow shell scripts to be encoded in UTF-8?

I can't find a simple way to change *just one little thing* and have the whole system just use UTF-8 files without having to worry about encoding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm fairly sure bash pays attention to your locale setting, so if it's UTF-8, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you don't use the UTF-8 BOM, you should be ok.

Comment: Bizarre that UTF-8 permits a BOM (byte order mark) at start of file, but it's true: http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom5 - as you imply, any use of this would confuse many applications such as shells.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to do anything, it's always worked automatically for me.